# What does "well defined up to isomorphism" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My Algebra textbook says the following:

> $A\cup B$ is defined as the union of $A'$ and $B'$, where $A'$ and $B'$ are isomorphic to $A$ and $B$ respectively. Hence, $A\cup B$ is not well-defined *as a set*, but it is well defined *up to isomorphism*.

1. What does "well-defined as a set" mean? Does it mean $A\cup B$ need not always have the **very same** elements?
2. What does "well defined up to isomorphism" mean? Does it mean that the set contains the very same elements if we consider isomorphic elements to be the same?

Comment: What textbook are you using?  Can you give some context?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan- I'm using "Chapter 0" by Aluffi.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure about the context in which this is said, but I'd say that "$A\cup B$ is not well-defined as a set but it is well defined up to isomorphism" means that if you replace $A$ and $B$ with isomorphic objects $A^\prime$ and $B^\prime$ then $A^\prime\cup B^\prime$ doesn't contain exactly the same elements of $A\cup B$, but it is nonetheless isomorphic to it.

A bit more of details about the occurence of this, might greatly help clarifying it.